# Анимация увеличения кнопки

Tags: wpf, xaml, анимация

С анимацией только начал разбираться. Поэтому на мой взгляд достаточно тривиальная задача поставила в ступор.

Разрабатывал пользовательский интерфейс

[image: Меню]

Верхние части помещены в ItemsControls.
Задача состоит в том, чтобы при наведении на элемент он выходил на передний план и немного увеличивался в размерах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал сделать через анимацию, но не нашел свойства ZIndex, а при изменении размеров все разъезжается в разные стороны.

```
                <ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource EventListStyle}">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
        </ItemsControl>

<DataTemplate x:Key="EventHeaderView">
    <Border CornerRadius="5,0,0,5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"  Background="White"
            Margin="5,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform/>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
        <Canvas Width="68" Height="68">
            <Button ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}" Width="68" Height="68"
                Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectedIndexCommand, ElementName=RootMain}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SystemName}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Avatar}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </Canvas>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="EventListStyle" TargetType="ItemsControl">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EventHeaderView}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Events}"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ZIndex` существует в виде attached property `Panel.ZIndex`, которое влияет на порядок отображения элементов на панели. Нюанс в том, что панелью является панель из `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`, а непосредственно в ней размещаются `ContentPresenter`, внутри которых уже содержимое `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`. Соответственно, необходимо повлиять на `Panel.ZIndex` того `ContentPresenter`, который содержит элемент под курсором. Один из таких способов — перекрыть стиль для всех `ContentPresenter` вашего `ItemsControl`, положив стиль в `ItemsControl.Resources`.

Чтобы контролы при увеличении выползали за границы контейнера, а не раздвигали элементы вокруг них, при этом их рендеринг не ограничивался прежней областью, можно положить увеличиваемые элементы в `Canvas` и увеличивать их анимированием `RenderTransform` с `ScaleTransform` внутри.

Полный пример:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <ItemsControl Margin="10" Width="60">
        <ItemsControl.Items>
            <system:String>Foo</system:String>
            <system:String>Bar</system:String>
            <system:String>Baz</system:String>
        </ItemsControl.Items>
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <Int32Animation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)" To="100" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <Int32Animation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
                <Canvas x:Name="panel" Width="40" Height="40">
                    <Button x:Name="button" Content="{Binding}" Width="40" Height="40" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5 0.5">
                        <Button.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                        </Button.RenderTransform>
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1.5" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
                </Canvas>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Здесь значение `ZIndex` тоже анимируется, причём до большого значения, чтобы при нескольких увеличенных кнопках сверху была самая большая, при этом увеличиваемая кнопка сразу становаилась выше других (достаточно достигнуть значения 1, чтобы стать выше остальных, у которых 0).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, идею я уловил.
Попробовал вставить Ваш код, чтобы посмотреть, что получиться кнопки действительно увеличиваются, только не из-за границ ItemsControl'a обрезаются... Может я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Канву не пропустили?

Comment: Нет, код прикрепил к вопросу. Попробовал Canvas и в Border, и наоборjт Border в Canvas.

Comment: @Vyacheslav Канва должна быть в корне. Могу посоветовать только метод выкидывания всего лишнего, пока не заработает. Так как мой пример работает, а ваш нет, то можно постепенно преобразовывать один в другой, пока не обнаружится источник проблемы. Ну вот у вас какой-то стиль у ItemsControl есть — для начала посмотрите, что в нём...

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое за ответ:)

Comment: @Vyacheslav Вам спасибо за вопрос, было интересно решать. :)